# Is accumulator logic heavy in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to check the flink performance using kafka source.
My process logic contains the aggregating the values.
When I see the metrics, `.aggregate` after `.keyBy` and `.window (TumblingWindow for 60sec)` caused the backpressured and it eventually affects the kafka source throughput.

I think that aggregting is just count the value using incoming data but my experiment showed me that it cause the upstream performance.

Is this real in flink?

Comment: This sort of computation doesn’t have to be expensive, but can be. It depends on what is being accumulated, how flink is configured (including the state backend), and the sink.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When removing the sink, the backPressured can be seen in the source. This indicates that the processing logic can cause the backPressured. Is this right?

Comment: That sounds right. If you share the code and configuration perhaps we can spot the problem. There are efficient and inefficient ways to do almost everything with Flink.